# Did I write down my model correctly using matrix algebra and LaTex?

Tags: regression, econometrics, notation

Model is essentially a seemingly unrelated regression estimation of the two following equations:

$lnIMR_i=\alpha_i^{IMR}+I_i\beta_i^{IMR}+C_i\theta_i^{IMR}+A_i\lambda_i^{IMR}+M_i\delta_i^{IMR}+Q_i\pi^{IMR}+u_i^{IMR}$

$lnU5MR_i=\alpha_i^{U5MR}+I_i\beta_i^{U5MR}+C_i\theta_i^{U5MR}+A_i\lambda_i^{U5MR}+M_i\delta_i^{U5MR}+Q_i\pi^{U5MR}+u_i^{U5MR}$

Where Greek letters are parameters to be estimated; I,C,A,M and Q are row vectors containing regressors and 'u_i' are disturbances.

Note that "$I_i\beta_i^{IMR}+C_i\theta_i^{IMR}+...$" are groups of row vectors,containing different regressors, multiplied times their corresponding coefficient column vector. I did this, in matrix form, to avoid having to write out: y=B1x1+B2X2+B3X3+.. etc. since my model is long and certain regressors can be grouped. For example "$I_i\beta_i^{IMR}$" represents a row vector of regressors, that fall under a group I call "I", being multiplied times a column vector of coefficients represented by beta which of course only pertains to that group. Likewise, "$C_i\theta_i^{IMR}$" is a row vector of regressors that fall under group "C", which are then multiplied times a column vector of coefficients only pertaining to that group, etc.

Is the model written down like this ok? Also, I tried putting data and coefficient vectors in bold to denote the use of vectors, but couldnt do it on latex - but, is this even necessary or is it implied by the fact that I have a data vector times a coefficient vector (instead of non-matrix form: $\beta_1X_1$)

EDIT: if all the regressors in a group of regressors are in natural log form (And I really want to specifiy that), can I write: $lnIMR_i=\alpha_i^{IMR}+lnI_i\beta_i^{IMR}+lnC_i\theta_i^{IMR}+...$ ??

Comment: I cannot make any sense of these equations because you have not clearly distinguished variables from coefficients from random error terms. In fact, you seem to be referring to their *products* as "regressors," which makes little sense.  IMHO it would help immensely to drop the "IMR" and "U5MR" superscripts because they create a lot of visual clutter and detract from the apparent point of your question. You could also simplify these equations by reducing the number of variables that appear in each: it seems to be immaterial whether you have two groups, half a dozen, or more.

Comment: There, i edited my post to clear up things. Also, I really do need 5 groups of regressors, since without them there would be around 21 regressors. The reason for the superscript is that i need to clearly differentiate that the beta vector for IMR is different than the beta vector for U5MR, even though in both cases they are being mutiiplied times the same I row vectors of regressors.

Comment: Why not just one $\boldsymbol{x\beta}$?

Comment: Scortchi: Because I essentially want to show the following model: http://i.imgur.com/XtUaH42.png and showing all the regressors would be ideal, but if not i'd like to show the 5 groups they fall under. Any suggestions if this is the case, based on the questions I raised on my original post?